# Custom TreelistEx field type which displays the Path of selected items

Tags: content-editor, custom-field, content

Is there some open-source custom field type for Sitecore which works similar to the TreelistEx field, but displays the paths of the selected items? Or perhaps, is there some way to configure the TreelistEx field source to include some more path info within the selected items?

So instead of having:
[image]

we might have something like:

[image]

Drawbacks of having a field type such as this are the potential for the order of stored SitecoreIds in the field value to be different to the order of items displayed, though this could potentially be mitigated with some re-ordering on save, perhaps.

Comment: Did you check this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24645/customize-treelist-field-appearance-in-content-editor

Comment: @GauravAgarwal that's a link to the same question/answer! It doesn't fully answer, but is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can check one of my blogs which details on how to extend multilist field to display item path on the field panel.

[image]

https://sitecorefoundation.in/sitecore-graphql-advance-search-queries/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Link only answers are not welcomed. Provide enough information to apply the change inside your answer. Use the link as the source of the information and potentially additional details.